# Transform array of arrays to array of hashes with new keys

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have array of arrays like this:

```
status = [
   ["Deleted", "deleted", 0],
   ["In planning", "planning", 1],
   ["In approval", "approval", 2]
]
```

How do I transform it to an array of hashes like this?

```
[
  {:label => "Deleted", :value => "deleted"},
  {:label => "In planning", :value => "planning"},
  {:label => "In approval", :value => "approval"}
]
```

So far I tried:

```
status.each do |s| label: s[0], value: s[1] end
```

However, I don't get back an array of hashes. If I do:

```
puts s[0], value: s[1]
```

I see only hashes in my console:

```
{:label => "Deleted", :value => "deleted"}
{:label => "In planning", :value => "planning"}
{:label => "In approval", :value => "approval"}
```

I believe I somehow would need to add those hashes to the array.

Comment: You can try `status.map { |s| {label: s[0], value: s[1]} }`

Comment: @BlueSmith Thank you, it works :) I tried similar as well, but without `.map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to the following:

```
status.map { |label, value, _| { label: label, value: value } }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
status.map{ |s| Hash[label: s[0], value: s[1]] }
# => [{:label=>"Deleted", :value=>"deleted"}, {:label=>"In planning", :value=>"planning"}, {:label=>"In approval", :value=>"approval"}]
```